# get current domain user php

Tags: php, active-directory

I'm creating a website on my local domain using Apache, PHP & MySQL.
I need to grab the current username that executes the script on the windows domain.

I've found some answers around different forums but none of them give a helpful answer.

Comment: You mean UNIX user or windows user?

Comment: sorry, should of clarified. Windows user.

Comment: @Roma, try echo exec("whoami"); exec function will help to run command prompt commands and get the result from it

Comment: @DhayalRam Will this return the name of the remote user running the script or the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it will be return name of user who access the website. you can change "echo" command with another command what you need

```
<?php echo exec("whoami");
?>
```